# ican't correct the error no such column in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

[my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVfEz.png)

What do i have to do?

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

my error is no such column and i"ve tried several times.

Answer (score 0):

you need to makemigrations after create your models.
first write this command in your terminal

**python manage.py makemigrations**

then:

**python manage.py migrate**

Comment: @KH write your app name after makemigrations

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py ?
If not try to register it.

Comment: like this?INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
]